# How to unit test a Singleton class of database connection using PHP PDO?

Tags: php, unit-testing, pdo, phpunit

I was writting a Singleton class of Database connection, but I ran into some problems. Look:

```php
class PDOSingleConnection
{
    private static PDO|null $pdo = null;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        self::$pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public static function getPDO(
        $hostName = 'localhost',
        $username = 'root',
        $password = '12345'
    ): PDO
    {
        if (is_null(self::$pdo)) {
            try {
                self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostName;", $username, $password);
                self::$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (\PDOException $PDOException) {
                throw new \PDOException($PDOException->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return self::$pdo;
    }
}
```

How you can see, I can't test it 'cause I can't mock my dependency(the PDO class).

My first question is: How can I improve this class, so that it is unit testable?

My second question is: I was reading some topics in the community, and I have seen some people saying that "Singletons are bad news". So, Why "Singletons are bad news"? How can I create a single instance of my database connection, without using the Singleton pattern?

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi, take a look here https://phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection to understand Dependency Injection which will solve your problem with singleton

Comment: "Singletons are bad news" is just an opinion, and hopefully they have backing reasons but if they don't I'd treat it the same as "blue is the best color" and move on. On a related, IMHO your constructor should be private otherwise you are defeating how singletons work. Actually, thinking even more, your singleton is more a factory with probably just a single return which should be an instance of `PDO`, otherwise you will constantly be writing `PDOSingleConnection::getPDO()->pdo`